# Optimizing node.js solution for HackerRank QHEAP1

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, heap

Hi I'm trying to familiarize myself a bit better with Heaps so wanted to try and implement a solution to [HackerRanks>Practice>Data Structures>Heaps>QHEAP1](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/qheap1/problem?isFullScreen=true) using primitives, however I'm getting a timeout error for two of the tests.

A quick summary: I need to be able to parse a standardized input and handle the following 3 types of queries:

1. Add an element to the heap.
2. Delete a specific element from the heap.
3. Print the minimum of all the elements in the heap.

I'm wondering where this could be optimized? From what I can tell my `del()` will be performed in O(n) since I need to search for the element provided.

```js
// search for and delete specific element {x} from heap
function del(arr, x){
  let i = 0;
  let found = false;
  let n = arr.length;
  while(!found && i < n){
      if(arr[i] == x) found = true;
      i++;
  }
  if(found){
      arr[i-1] = arr[n-1];  // take the last element and overwrite to delete
      arr.length = n - 1;  // shorten array
      downHeap(arr, i);  // perform downHeap opertaion from index deleted
  }
}
// NOTE: customized for minHeap due to requirement to print minimum value
function downHeap(arr, t){
  // use array as binary tree - next index looking down is double current index
  // NOTE: i and t are 1 indexed for heap lookahead
  let i = 2 * t;  
  if(i >= arr.length) return;  // no more room
  // checkes if right child is smallest - if so updates index to right child
  if(i < arr.length - 1 && arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) i = i + 1;
  
  // if lower element is smaller than current element, swap em
  if(arr[i-1] < arr[t-1]){
      swap(arr, i-1, t-1);
      downHeap(arr,i);  // downHeap again at the next level
  } 
}

// insert x into heap 
function insert(arr, x){
  const n = arr.length;
  arr.length = n + 1;  // increasing array size
  arr[n] = x;  // adding el to end of array
  upHeap(arr, arr.length)
}

//NOTE: customized as minHeap due to requirement to print minimum value.
function upHeap(arr, t){
  // using array as binary tree - looking up - parant is half of current index
  const i = Math.floor(t/2);
  // if we've hit zero gone too far - NOTE: i, and t are 1 indexed for heap reference
  // also nothing to do if parent is smaller than current index
  if(i == 0 || arr[i-1] <= arr[t-1]) return;
  
  // child is smaller than parent swap and upHeap from parent
  swap(arr, t-1, i-1)
  upHeap(arr, i)
}

// swahp 
function swap(arr, l, r){
  const t = arr[l];
  arr[l] = arr[r];
  arr[r] = t;
}
```

PS. as a side question, I'm kind of switching between a `1` indexed for heap operations, and a `0` index for array operations (e.g. you'll notices a lot of `i-1` statements inside the up and downHeap methods) - wondering if there's a smarter way of having done that?

Support Code:

```js
function processData(input) {
    //Enter your code here
    const inputs = input.split('\n');
    const n = inputs[0];
    let arr = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        const query = inputs[i].split(' ');
        const op = query[0];
        if(op == "1"){
            insert(arr, parseInt(query[1]))
        } else if(op == "2"){
            del(arr, parseInt(query[1]))
        } else if(op == "3"){
            console.log(arr[0])
        } else {
            console.log("Error reading op");
        }
    }
} 

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = "";
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
    _input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
   processData(_input);
});
```

Example Input

```
22
1 286789035
1 255653921
1 274310529
1 494521015
3
2 255653921
2 286789035
3
1 236295092
1 254828111
2 254828111
1 465995753
1 85886315
1 7959587
1 20842598
2 7959587
3
1 -51159108
3
2 -51159108
3
1 789534713
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is indeed confusing because (as you write) it sometimes uses 1-based indexes, while other times it uses them as 0-based.

For instance, in `insert`, the following line shows that you intend `t` and `i` to be a 1-based index, since you convert them on-the-fly to a 0-based index:

```
if(arr[i-1] < arr[t-1])
```

...but then in this line, you treat `i` as a 0-based index (`arr.length` would be an admissible value of `i` if it is 1-based):

```
if(i >= arr.length) return;  // no more room
```

And the same mix-up happens here:

```
if(i < arr.length - 1 && arr[i - 1] > arr[i]) i = i + 1;
```

By consequence you will get wrong results.

It is confusing to work with 1-based indexes when JavaScript is expecting 0-based indexes everywhere indexes are used. I didn't feel the courage to further debug your code in that state. I would suggest to use 0-based indexes throughout your code, which means that the left child of a value at index `t` is at index `t*2+1`.

Some other remarks:

- To find the index where a value occurs in the heap, you don't have to write an explicit loop. Just use the built-in `indexOf` method.
- Recursion is nice, but the `downHeap` and `upHeap` functions will work more efficiently with an iterative method, because then -- instead of swapping values -- you can take a copy of the value to bubble up or down, and then only *move* (not swap) the conflicting values to finally insert the copied value in its right place. This will perform fewer assignments than swapping repeatedly.
- To insert a value you can just use the `push` method instead of updating the `length` "manually".
- Instead of `Math.floor` for the integer division by 2, you can use a shift operator.

So here is a correction of your code:

```
function del(arr, x) {
    const i = arr.indexOf(x); // This will be faster
    if (i >= 0) {
        const value = arr.pop();
        if (i < arr.length) { // Only assign back when it was not last
            arr[i] = value;
            downHeap(arr, i);
        }
    }
}

function downHeap(arr, t) {
    const val = arr[t];
    while (true) {
        let i = t * 2 + 1;
        if (i < arr.length - 1 && arr[i] > arr[i + 1]) i = i + 1;
        if (i >= arr.length || arr[i] >= val) break;
        arr[t] = arr[i]; // Don't swap to gain time
        // No recursion to save stack space
        t = i;
    }
    arr[t] = val;
}

function insert(arr, x) {
    arr.push(x);  // adding element to end of array
    upHeap(arr, arr.length - 1);
}

function upHeap(arr, t) {
    const val = arr[t];
    while (true) {
        let i = (t - 1) >> 1; // Shift operator may give some speed increase
        if (i < 0 || arr[i] <= val) break;
        arr[t] = arr[i]; // Don't swap to gain time
        // No recursion to save stack space
        t = i;
    }
    arr[t] = val;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the review! The comments were much appreciated! Was able to get all tests to pass.